# How does Tor collect addresses of nodes?

Tags: tls, anonymity, tor

My name is Alice and I would like to send a package to my beloved Bob. In order to avoid getting recognized by Bob I decide to send my message through several nodes. At each step, a node decrypts the message he received reading:

- the address of next node
- an encrypted message.

He will then proceed to send it to the address he found in the uncrypted message.

In order to securly encrypt my message I need to know the address of every node and their public keys. How does Tor collects such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Tor software comes with a list of predefined *directory authorities*. These authorities maintain signed lists of *relays* from which your client can choose to build the connection. A new relay publishes a *server descriptor* to the authorities to advertise itself.

Since not every Tor client acts as a relay, the number is smaller than you might assume and you don't need to somehow aggregate the node list yourself.

The [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#KeyManagement) explains this pretty well:

> **Coordination:** How do clients know what the relays are, and how do they
>   know that they have the right keys for them? Each relay has a
>   long-term public signing key called the "identity key". Each directory
>   authority additionally has a "directory signing key". The directory
>   authorities [provide a signed list](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) of all the known relays, and in that
>   list are a set of certificates from each relay (self-signed by their
>   identity key) specifying their keys, locations, exit policies, and so
>   on. So unless the adversary can control a majority of the directory
>   authorities (as of 2012 there are 8 directory authorities), he can't
>   trick the Tor client into using other Tor relays.

You can explore the bridges and relays at [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) or [Globe](https://globe.torproject.org/).